# Propagation of modularity and the Artin conjecture

Tags: nt.number-theory, galois-representations, l-functions, langlands-conjectures

The (still incomplete) solution of the Artin conjecture on dimension $\leq2$ has been a massive research effort that has spanned (knowingly or not) around a century.

A very natural question is, what is the relation between the known cases, and an eventual proof of the conjecture in all dimensions. This is usually answered with "almost nothing is known beyond dimension 2" o "the methods are not expected to generalize".

But the fact is, that both philosophically and in practice, different instances of the conjecture (in different dimension or different image) tend to be related often enough. Here are some examples (some of them from (our own) Kimball Martin's  thesis):

- The 2-dimensional icosahedral case implies the 3-dimensional icosahedral, by the Gelbart-Jacquet lift.
- Non-normal quintic base change for $\mathrm{GL}_4$ would imply all the irreducible 4-dimensional solvables left ($E_{2^4} \cdot D_{10}$ and $E_{2^4} \cdot F_{20}$).
- Adjunction of 3-dimensional $G_{72}$ representations yields unconditionally an irreducible 8-dimensional case (even if the original 3-dim case in not known to be modular).
- Representations of dimension $2^j$ or $2^j\cdot 3$ with supersolvable image are modular.
- Known 2-dimensional icosahedral cases and Asai transfer prove (all?) irreducible $S_5$ representations in dimension $4$, $5$ and $6$ ([paper by Frank Calegari](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~fcale/papers/S5A.pdf))
- For $m\leq 5$, $\mathrm{sym}^m(\rho)$ with $\rho$ 2-dimensional gets you modularity of representations of dimensions $3$, $4$, $5$, $6$ (Gelbart, Jacquet, Kim, Shahidi).
- $\Lambda^2 (\rho)$ for $\rho$ 4-dimensional.
- Various tensor products of modular representations of low dimension.

*(If I have mistaken some result, of you want to add some other, feel free to edit or comment!)*

If you consider not only irreducible representation, but reducible or monomial, the propagation of modularity from known cases to new ones is even more drastic.

> What I'm trying to understand is whether it known or expected/conjectured that in
>   order to prove the full Artin conjecture, it might be enough to prove
>   a finite number of cases (or finite family of cases).
>
> To put it another way, is there point after which functoriality, base
>   changes, lifts... is expected to give you all the remaining cases?
>   This point could be a fixed dimension, or a family of particular base
>   cases.

*Perhaps this is too broad or speculative. I'm open to refine the question depending on the feedback.*

Comment: Functoriality gives you everything, but functoriality is the holy grail. If you only have fragments of functoriality like base change in degree <= 2015 or whatever, then how are you going to deal with representations of gigantic degree of a Galois extension of number fields with Galois group $SL(N,k)$ with $N>>2015$ and $k$ a finite field of size $>>2015$?? This question doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: I just saw this question.  To add to eric's comment, if you know functoriality for arbitrary base changes or arbitrary induction (including for non-normal extensions), then that is sufficient for the (strong) Artin conjecture.  I believe this was first observed by Clozel.  Is this the sort of thing you wanted to know, or something different?

Comment: @Kimball I guess the question is, what are the "minimal" results in functoriality that imply the Artin conjecture? Of course strong results like base change are sufficient, but are they neccesary?

Comment: My guess is that you can't get by with much less.  The reason is that there's no simple way to construct all irreps of finite groups except inducing from the trivial representation.  So if your group is non-normal, this amounts to knowing non-normal induction (or dually, base change) (at least for isobaric representations of "Artin type").

Comment: By the way, in your list of examples, when you use functoriality (e.g., ext sq or sym powers) lifts from GL(2), the result is only known if your 2-dim $\rho$ is known to be modular.

Comment: @Kimball I think what I'm looking for is that "not simple way" to construct irreducible representations without induction or base change. I realize the question is probably too broad and unnatural.